# How to replace an en-dash in a citation with multiple references using Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, punctuation

I want to stop my *.bbx file from forcing references into:

```
[1-5]
```

But rather I would like cited papers to be shown as:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I have found various answers but they mainly point out to changing the style. This does not apply in my case as I created my own style.
Therefore, my question is:
Which command in style file is responsible for the way cited papers look and how to modify it?
Thanks.

I am using following setting for biblatex:

```
\usepackage[
natbib=true, 
backend=biber, 
sorting=none,
style=mine,
date=year, 
giveninits=true,
url=false,
citestyle=numeric-comp,
maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `citestyle=numeric` instead of `citestyle=numeric-comp`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @ARTICLE{smit54,
        AUTHOR = {J. G. Smith and H. K. Weston},
        TITLE = {Nothing Particular in this Year's History},
        YEAR = {1954},
        JOURNAL = {J. Geophys. Res.},
        VOLUME = {2},
        PAGES = {14-15}
    }
    @BOOK{colu92,
        AUTHOR = {Christopher Columbus},
        TITLE = {How {I} Discovered {America}},
        YEAR = {1492},
        PUBLISHER = {Hispanic Press},
        ADDRESS = {Barcelona}
    }
    @ARTICLE{gree00,
        AUTHOR = {R. J. Green and U. P. Fred and W. P. Norbert},
        TITLE = {Things that Go Bump in the Night},
        YEAR = {1900},
        JOURNAL = {Psych. Today},
        VOLUME = {46},
        PAGES = {345-678}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
    natbib=true, 
    backend=biber, 
    sorting=none,
%   bibstyle=mine, % good suggestion by @moewe; uncomment this line in your document
    citestyle=numeric,
    date=year, 
    giveninits=true,
    url=false,
    maxbibnames=10
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \section{First section}
    \cite{smit54,colu92,gree00}

    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1) But in the example (and also more generally) I recommend that people only use `bibstyle` and `citestyle` when absolutely necessary and otherwise prefer `style`, which sets both `bibstyle` and `citestyle` at the same time. So instead of `citestyle=numeric,` I would just say `style=numeric,` here (which incidentally is the default, so need not strictly speaking be included, but I think it is good practice to always specify the `style` explicitly to avoid confusion even if it happens to be the default).

Comment: @moewe OP uses their own style (which I commented out here, because I don't have it), so leaving the default wasn't an option; and without knowing what's specified in ``mine``, I thought the easiest solution (at least for OP) is to force a different ``citestyle``.

Comment: Mhh, fair enough I hadn't seen the commented `%style=mine,`, sorry. If that is to be used I'd prefer `bibstyle=mine, citestyle=numeric,` to make explicitly which style controls which bit of the output.